# Repeated squaring vs. regular modular exponentiation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I initially thought I would use repeated squaring for computations of the for $a^b \ mod \ c$ for large values of $a$ and $c$. Is there a better way to decide?

Comment: What do you mean by regular modular exponentiation? If it means raising a to appropriate powers to compute $a^b mod c$ then realise that repeated squaring is just a special case of regular modular exponentiation and so the latter method is obviously more flexible.

Comment: If $\gcd(a,c)=1$ you can use Fermat's little theorem to reduce the exponent $b$, then apply repeated squaring.

Comment: Repeated squaring, or more precisely [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is most useful when $b$ is large. Necessarily then $c$ is also large for otherwise tricks like little Fermat allow you to replace $b$ with a smaller number. The size of $a$ is mostly irrelevant.